# Is this text American or British English? Please, I need the American version

Tags: american-english

*Ann has taught university level Film classes and has a Master's Degree in Cinema Studies.*

Comment: It would pass in either major dialect.  There's nothing telltale about it linguistically or culturally that points to one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no words here to differentiate between between the two dialects at all, so it passes for both. Potentially, "University" and "Master's Degree" might have a different meaning between the two countries, but neither by itself points to any particular dialect. **It's okay to use this in the context of American English**, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell whether this statement is American or British English, because of the context.

You might find this surprising, because this sentence uses a word where there *is* a big distinction between the two dialects.  In specific, British English typically uses the word "film" while American English would typically call it a "movie".  Likewise, British English will call the building a "cinema" while American English uses the phrase "movie theater".  The issue here, however, is that this sentence is referring to an academic setting.  In *academia*, both British and American English will use the words "film" and "cinema".

As a side note, this is one reason why Americans often have the idea that British people sound more intellectual-- many common British English words are also American English words, just exclusively in the academic register.

Comment: But OTOH Brits more usually say "MA" or "MSc" than "Master's Degree".

Comment: Many US and British academic style guides advise against capitalising descriptions of qualifications e.g. a master's degree in cinema studies.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, if I were writing the sentence, the only capital letter would be at the start of the sentence. This is true regardless of region.